# Why does HTML5 Boilerplate use Normalize.css v1.x and not latest v2.x?

Tags: html5boilerplate

The question is in the title: "Why does HTML5 Boilerplate use Normalize.css v1.x and not latest v2.x?" - I'm sure there's a good reason for this, perhaps retaining IE6/7 compatibility?

Comment: yeah, as far as I'm aware, it's just for compatibility with IE6/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's it exactly. The current version of HTML5 Boilerplate retains old IE support so it relies on Normalize 1.x. [For direct evidence, see issue 1260.](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1260) [Issue 1050](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1050), which is the meta issue dealing with dropping legacy support, contains much discussion of this and other legacy compatibility issues. HTML5 Boilerplate [v5.0](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues?milestone=5&state=open) will be the catalyst for bumping normalize to 2.x